# How to get my result in decimal precision control with power value?

Tags: java, android, decimal, precision

In my calculation program I am getting Result is 2.04145124554 e-5 so I want to control the result with decimal precision. I used the code 
String.format("%.2f",myans)
now I am getting the result 0.00
but I expected result is 2.04 e-5
now what i do?

Comment: Please show the code so we know what types you are using.

Answer (score 0):

change it to

String.format ("%1.2f",myans)

Answer (score 0):

The DecimalFormat class can help you here (more information on http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html
).

The following code outputs "2.04E-5"

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##E0");
System.out.println(df.format(2.04145124554e-5));
// prints: 2.04E-5
```